# Unable to download csv file from iShares website

Tags: python, csv, download

all by using the code below (link checked, it is correct) I get an HTML file as a result instead of .csv if I were to use a browser like Chrome.

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239726/ishares-core-sp-500-etf/1467271812596.ajax?filetype=csv&filename=ivv_holdings&datatype=fund', "file.csv")
```

What would be a good solution to this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe problem is you have not been careful about the spelling.  You have `filename`, `filetype` and `datatype`, whereas the site requires `fileName`, `fileType`, and `dataType`.  The capitalization must match.